# Determining homogenous blocks of individual tree species in woodland and creating new shapefile without blocks/polygons of < minimum area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, buffer, area, dissolve

I am working on a project attempting to identify suitable woodland habitat for red squirrel translocation wherein conservation efforts could be focused. Below is a small section of the map showing where individual tree species polygons have been dissolved, using a 100m buffer dissolve, to appear as larger "wooded area" polygons.

For the purpose of my project, I want to identify suitable forest areas over 200ha in size, with a suitable make up of tree species. To do this I need to determine homogenous blocks as seperate from those they are not in contact with, and then determine the size and make up of these blocks. There are ~150,000 polygons in the shapefile, so manually selecting each is not a possibility.

I think some form of spatial dissolve would be most suitable, Identifying one homogenous block as "Block 1" for example, and then using Select by Attributes to create a new shapefile with only polygons ("Blocks") with an area greater than 200ha.

How do I do this?

I am very limited in my knowledge of GIS, and had the help of a phd student as well as some on here in getting this far.

I aming ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap) 9.3, with ArcInfo licence type.

[image: Individual tree species polygons dissolved (with 100m buffer dissolve) to appear as larger "wooded area" polygon]

Comment: Which software do you currently use? You could union the buffered data (getting a multipolygon), then split the multipolygon into the polygons it consists of, then calculate the area of the polygon and select only those polygons with area > 200 ha

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your quick response. I have edited my original post now to include my software  (I am using ArcGIS/ArcMap for Desktop 9.3, with ArcInfo licence type). Is that sufficient to run the tasks you suggested?
I assume I use the Union Analysis tool to get the multipolygon, but how then do I split this in to polygons again?
My apologies if this is basic stuff!

Comment: Hi! To generate single Polygons, the "Multipart to Singlepart" - function can be used (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Multipart_To_Singlepart/00170000003r000000/)